# after included the shiro-core and shiro-web in maven getting error

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, netbeans, shiro

My maven web project is working fine before i included the `shiro-core-1.2.2` and `shiro-web-1.2.2`
but after i include this dependency in pom.xml then i getting error at the time of 
mvn tomee:deploy. and this same project code after arranging project structure if i execute in eclipse then is working fine but in maven and in netbeans is not working .its display error

```
SEVERE: Can't find of appInfo for C:\my_work\Snefocaremaven\target\Snefocaremaven.war, availables: [C:\App\apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.5.2\webapps\Demo, C:\App\apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.5.2\webapps\host-manager, C:\App\apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.5.2\webapps\tomee, C:\App\apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.5.2\webapps\ROOT, C:\App\apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.5.2\webapps\docs, C:\App\apache-tomee-jaxrs-1.5.2\webapps\manager]
```

in catalina log file. and the full trace of message is here:
    http://www.docdroid.net/5prk/shiro-error.txt.html

Comment: This error SEVERE: Error listenerStart ofthen means there is something wrong with a servlet filter, or a servlet. There may be an additional stacktrace in the localhost.log as that is where the stdout and stderr goes to in tomcat. See if you can find it to provide additional info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may you need to include the library in netbean and the pom.xml .you can refer this link for solution.
i hope this will solve your problem.

see this link::[Get apache shiro to work in netbeans without maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14671147/get-apache-shiro-to-work-in-netbeans-without-maven)